# NOT NULL constraint failed: blogs_comment.blog_id

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I'm a beginner at django please help I've been trying to solve it for 2 hours, Thank you so much!

<I got this django error IntegrityError at /blog/431cdef3-d9e7-4abd-bf53-eaa7b188d0fd>

python
#Views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Blog
from .forms import CommentForm

def home(request):
    template = 'blogs/home.html'
    blogs = Blog.objects.all()
    context = {'blogs':blogs}

    return render(request, template, context)

def blog(request, pk):
    template = 'blogs/blog.html'
    blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=pk)
    context = {'blog':blog}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        form.save()
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, template, context)
```

#Forms

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Comment
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['description']
```

#Models

```
from django.db import models
import uuid


class Blog(models.Model):
    header = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    posts = models.TextField(null=True)
    footer = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.header

class Comment(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.description `
```

Comment: You need to call `form.is_valid()` before `form.save()` in order to check if the data being passed can be saved to DB,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
    def blog(request, pk):
        template = 'blogs/blog.html'
        blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=pk)
        context = {'blog':blog}
    
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CommentForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                comment = form.save(commit=False) # don't save the comment yet
                comment.blog = blog # assign the blog
                comment.save() # then save
        else:
            form = CommentForm()
        context['form'] = form
        return render(request, template, context)
```

Add the blog to the comment first before committing the comment to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add with `Foreignkey key` value. Try this one.

```
def blog(request, pk):
    template = 'blogs/blog.html'
    blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=pk)
    context = {'blog':blog}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST, instance=blog)
        if form.is_valid():
      
            form.save()
    else:
        form = CommentForm(instance=blog)
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, template, context)
```